# How to fetch data into AWS SageMaker using API

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, python-requests, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker

**Krutarth Pujara** here,

Below Code is how fetching data is described in the tutorial of AWS SageMaker:

```
try:
  urllib.request.urlretrieve ("https://d1.awsstatic.com/tmt/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/bank_clean.27f01fbbdf43271788427f3682996ae29ceca05d.csv", "bank_clean.csv")
  print('Success: downloaded bank_clean.csv.')
except Exception as e:
  print('Data load error: ',e)

try:
  model_data = pd.read_csv('./bank_clean.csv',index_col=0)
  print('Success: Data loaded into dataframe.')
except Exception as e:
    print('Data load error: ',e)
```

Line to focus:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve ("https://d1.awsstatic.com/tmt/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/bank_clean.27f01fbbdf43271788427f3682996ae29ceca05d.csv", "bank_clean.csv")
```

The function used: `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`

And passes the parameter: link to csv

Parameter I want to pass: API link

That API contains Paginated JSON Data that I want to fetch Page-wise and

Finally store in one csv that I can store in S3 bucket using SageMaker.

**How to fetch data into AWS SageMaker using API?**

Comment: When you ask about SageMaker, do you mean the notebook service? If you want to get data for development purposes, you just need to use the Python code to do that and configure the API Gateway to return the pages.

Comment: When we create SageMaker Jupyter Instance, It creates a server instance for that, in that server instance we can create as many notebooks as we want, just like we create in our localhost.

I accomplished fetching data from API the same way i did in localhost